# list of xts objects back to list after merge

Tags: r, list, merge, xts

I have a list of xts objects

```
set.seed(1)
library(xts)
tm <- Sys.time()+1:10
f <- function(){
  m <- matrix(1:40,ncol = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("x",1:4))) 
  xts(m ,tm)[-sample(10,sample(9,1))]
}  

li <- lapply(1:3,\(x) f())
names(li) <- paste0("Obj ", 1:length(li))

li

$`Obj 1`
                    x1 x2 x3 x4
2024-03-06 18:26:05  6 16 26 36

$`Obj 2`
                    x1 x2 x3 x4
2024-03-06 18:26:01  2 12 22 32
2024-03-06 18:26:02  3 13 23 33
2024-03-06 18:26:03  4 14 24 34
2024-03-06 18:26:05  6 16 26 36
2024-03-06 18:26:06  7 17 27 37
2024-03-06 18:26:07  8 18 28 38
2024-03-06 18:26:09 10 20 30 40

$`Obj 3`
                    x1 x2 x3 x4
2024-03-06 18:26:01  2 12 22 32
2024-03-06 18:26:02  3 13 23 33
2024-03-06 18:26:03  4 14 24 34
2024-03-06 18:26:07  8 18 28 38
```

I need to align these list objects using `merge` and return them back to the list.

```
merge_li <- do.call(merge, li)
                    x1 x2 x3 x4 x1.1 x2.1 x3.1 x4.1 x1.2 x2.2 x3.2 x4.2
2024-03-06 18:26:01 NA NA NA NA    2   12   22   32    2   12   22   32
2024-03-06 18:26:02 NA NA NA NA    3   13   23   33    3   13   23   33
2024-03-06 18:26:03 NA NA NA NA    4   14   24   34    4   14   24   34
2024-03-06 18:26:05  6 16 26 36    6   16   26   36   NA   NA   NA   NA
2024-03-06 18:26:06 NA NA NA NA    7   17   27   37   NA   NA   NA   NA
2024-03-06 18:26:07 NA NA NA NA    8   18   28   38    8   18   28   38
2024-03-06 18:26:09 NA NA NA NA   10   20   30   40   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Now how to return the `merge_li` back to `li` (list) form?
And save the names of the `li` and preferably the columns inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id_xts <- li |> lapply(index) |> do.call(what = c) |> unique() |> sort() |> as.xts()

lapply(li, merge, id_xts, all = TRUE)

$`Obj 1`
                    x1 x2 x3 x4
2024-03-07 22:00:34 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:35 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:36 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:38  6 16 26 36
2024-03-07 22:00:39 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:40 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:42 NA NA NA NA

$`Obj 2`
                    x1 x2 x3 x4
2024-03-07 22:00:34  2 12 22 32
2024-03-07 22:00:35  3 13 23 33
2024-03-07 22:00:36  4 14 24 34
2024-03-07 22:00:38  6 16 26 36
2024-03-07 22:00:39  7 17 27 37
2024-03-07 22:00:40  8 18 28 38
2024-03-07 22:00:42 10 20 30 40

$`Obj 3`
                    x1 x2 x3 x4
2024-03-07 22:00:34  2 12 22 32
2024-03-07 22:00:35  3 13 23 33
2024-03-07 22:00:36  4 14 24 34
2024-03-07 22:00:38 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:39 NA NA NA NA
2024-03-07 22:00:40  8 18 28 38
2024-03-07 22:00:42 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: The reason for `as.POSIXct()` is clear but can be avoided, since `unlist` is dropping the class. Replace `unlist(.)` with `do.call(c, .)` (yes, just `c` as the function), and it'll do what you want and preserve the class/attributes. A succinct one-liner is `lapply(li, merge, as.xts(unique(sort(do.call(c, lapply(li, index))))), all = TRUE)`.