# list of dataframes back to list after merge

Tags: r, dataframe, list, merge, reduce

I have a list of dataframes with different numbers of rows but a single `id`

```
set.seed(1)
f <- function(){
  m <- matrix(1:40,ncol = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("x",1:4)))
  m <- cbind.data.frame(id=1:10, m)
  m[-sample(10,sample(9,1)),]
  
}  
li <- lapply(1:5,\(x) f())  ; names(li) <- paste0("Obj ", 1:length(li))
li

$`Obj 1`
  id x1 x2 x3 x4
6  6  6 16 26 36

$`Obj 2`
   id x1 x2 x3 x4
2   2  2 12 22 32
3   3  3 13 23 33
4   4  4 14 24 34
6   6  6 16 26 36
7   7  7 17 27 37
8   8  8 18 28 38
10 10 10 20 30 40

$`Obj 3`
  id x1 x2 x3 x4
2  2  2 12 22 32
3  3  3 13 23 33
4  4  4 14 24 34
8  8  8 18 28 38

$`Obj 4`
  id x1 x2 x3 x4
6  6  6 16 26 36

$`Obj 5`
   id x1 x2 x3 x4
1   1  1 11 21 31
4   4  4 14 24 34
5   5  5 15 25 35
7   7  7 17 27 37
9   9  9 19 29 39
10 10 10 20 30 40
```

I need to merge them all together

```
merged_df <- Reduce(\(x,y) merge(x, y, by = "id", all = T), li)

merged_df
 id x1.x x2.x x3.x x4.x x1.y x2.y x3.y x4.y x1.x x2.x x3.x x4.x x1.y x2.y x3.y x4.y x1 x2 x3 x4
1   1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  1 11 21 31
2   2   NA   NA   NA   NA    2   12   22   32    2   12   22   32   NA   NA   NA   NA NA NA NA NA
3   3   NA   NA   NA   NA    3   13   23   33    3   13   23   33   NA   NA   NA   NA NA NA NA NA
4   4   NA   NA   NA   NA    4   14   24   34    4   14   24   34   NA   NA   NA   NA  4 14 24 34
5   5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  5 15 25 35
6   6    6   16   26   36    6   16   26   36   NA   NA   NA   NA    6   16   26   36 NA NA NA NA
7   7   NA   NA   NA   NA    7   17   27   37   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  7 17 27 37
8   8   NA   NA   NA   NA    8   18   28   38    8   18   28   38   NA   NA   NA   NA NA NA NA NA
9   9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  9 19 29 39
10 10   NA   NA   NA   NA   10   20   30   40   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 10 20 30 40
```

And then return it back to the list while preserving the original names of the columns that were originally in the list and preserving the names of each list object that were originally.

How can I do that?

**=========UPD========**

here is my original list

```
$`Obj 1`
  id x1 x2
1  1  1  4
3  3  3  6

$`Obj 2`
  id x1 x2
2  2  2  5
3  3  3  6
```

I want to get this

```
$Obj1
  id x1 x2
1  1  1  4
2  2 NA NA
3  3  3  6

$Obj2
  id x1 x2
1  1 NA NA
2  2  2  5
3  3  3  6
```

Comment: It would be incredibly useful to know (exactly) what the intended final object is. Also, you mention a "single id" but most of the embedded frames have multiple `id` values, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: each object in the list has one `id` column.
I would like to get a list of the original objects but with rows with values `NA` where there were not enough values in the `id`.
`merged_df` shows what it should look like

Comment: to put it even simpler, I need to return the same objects back to the same list but with `NA` values

Comment: I still don't understand what your desired output is. So it's not `merged_df`? Can you maybe use a smaller example so you can provide exactly what you are trying to create for your sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a reduction, I suspect it's just enforcing all `id`s in all frames.

```r
lapply(li, merge,
   data.frame(id = sort(unique(unlist(lapply(li, `[[`, "id"))))),
   by = "id", all = TRUE)
# $`Obj 1`
#    id x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1   1 NA NA NA NA
# 2   2 NA NA NA NA
# 3   3 NA NA NA NA
# 4   4 NA NA NA NA
# 5   5 NA NA NA NA
# 6   6  6 16 26 36
# 7   7 NA NA NA NA
# 8   8 NA NA NA NA
# 9   9 NA NA NA NA
# 10 10 NA NA NA NA
# $`Obj 2`
#    id x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1   1 NA NA NA NA
# 2   2  2 12 22 32
# 3   3  3 13 23 33
# 4   4  4 14 24 34
# 5   5 NA NA NA NA
# 6   6  6 16 26 36
# 7   7  7 17 27 37
# 8   8  8 18 28 38
# 9   9 NA NA NA NA
# 10 10 10 20 30 40
# $`Obj 3`
#    id x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1   1 NA NA NA NA
# 2   2  2 12 22 32
# 3   3  3 13 23 33
# 4   4  4 14 24 34
# 5   5 NA NA NA NA
# 6   6 NA NA NA NA
# 7   7 NA NA NA NA
# 8   8  8 18 28 38
# 9   9 NA NA NA NA
# 10 10 NA NA NA NA
# $`Obj 4`
#    id x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1   1 NA NA NA NA
# 2   2 NA NA NA NA
# 3   3 NA NA NA NA
# 4   4 NA NA NA NA
# 5   5 NA NA NA NA
# 6   6  6 16 26 36
# 7   7 NA NA NA NA
# 8   8 NA NA NA NA
# 9   9 NA NA NA NA
# 10 10 NA NA NA NA
# $`Obj 5`
#    id x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1   1  1 11 21 31
# 2   2 NA NA NA NA
# 3   3 NA NA NA NA
# 4   4  4 14 24 34
# 5   5  5 15 25 35
# 6   6 NA NA NA NA
# 7   7  7 17 27 37
# 8   8 NA NA NA NA
# 9   9  9 19 29 39
# 10 10 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: Once again... faster & cleaner.

Comment: Perhaps we should recommend a lightning-round of StackOverflow questions at the next R conference ;-)

Comment: The last couple years I've intended to submit a talk on how to get the most out of SO, but I keep missing (or being unaware of) the deadlines to submit.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I do the same with a  xts object?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116024/list-of-xts-objects-back-to-list-after-merge

Comment: I was just about to answer when I saw you figured something out yourself, nice! I added a comment that's more of a slight-tweak, hope it helps. Good luck!